# Mac Terminal error: -bash: /Users/tim/.profile: No such file or directory

Tags: terminal

Every time I open a new Terminal window I see the following.

```
-bash: /Users/tim/.profile: No such file or directory
```

I have no idea why this is happening or where to look to fix it; my profile is located at `/Users/tim/.bash_profile` not `/Users/tim/.profile`

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This happened to me as well and I noticed that at the top of my `.bash_profile` it had:

```
source ~/.profile
```

My understanding is that on MacOS / OS X `.bash_profile` is given priority over `.profile` so the latter file isn't required.

To fix therefore I simply removed `source ~/.profile` from the top of the file.

Hope that helps.

Edit: original poster commented that he just created a blank `.profile` to solve this as well.

Comment: In my case I just created an empty `~/.profile` file and it the message disappeared. Will give you the credit since you're the only one who answered. :)

Answer (score 10):

I met the same issue today, i guess it's because i use the cleaning app and the app considered this file was a waste of space so deleted it. `touch ~/.profile` helps me.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue after I switched to an M1 chip MacBook. I found the solution, follow these steps should fix the issue:

1st: **Add below codes to `~/.bash_profile` (simply run this code in Terminal)**

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

2nd: **Run the below codes in Terminal**

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

This should fix the issue, you can check nvm -v. However, if the issue persists, try the below steps:

**Open the `~/.zshrc` file, and add the below codes at the top of the file and save.**

```
source ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.zshrc
```

(if you don't know how to access the `~/.zshrc` add whatever code editor in front of it in Terminal, I use VS code thus code `~/.zshrc`).
This should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Simply open .bash_profile file and comment on the first line.

in my case

```
source ~/.profile
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

to

```
#source ~/.profile
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

> Another way you just create the file in same folder where
>   .**bash_profile** exists.

But the first one is good if you don't need .profile for any purpose

Answer (score 0):

My problem was i didn't have "" when setting variables.

I changed
`export TEST=SOME_VAR`
to
`export TEST="SOME_VAR"`
and it was working again

Answer (score 0):

"
When you start a Terminal window, the shell, zsh, executes the code in ".zprofile" and this is trying to access a file called ".profile".

You need to edit the .zprofile to remove these offending lines.

If you are unsure about what this code is doing, you should probably not make changes to it.

Instead, I suggest you do this: rename this file, and then see if things are working normally.

In more detail:

a) In Terminal, rename .zprofile to something different, for example ".zprofile-inactive":

mv .zprofile .zprofile-inactive

b) Quit Terminal, and start it again "