# How to fix a Bash issue in macOS

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm here to show you my problem and to find a solution to a bash problem.Every time I launch my terminal under macOS, the first message that appears is "-bash: /Users/kiri/.profile: No such file or directory".

I have done nothing but open my terminal and it displays this message.

I tried to restart but nothing changes.

Thank you for helping me !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac Terminal error: -bash: /Users/tim/.profile: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157445/mac-terminal-error-bash-users-tim-profile-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a bash shell opens it attempts to read a file named .profile. This file should exist in your user directory but apparently isn't there. You should check if you have a .bash_profile as well.

Try creating a .profile file by typing `touch .profile` on the command line. Make sure you are in your home directory when you do this. After creating the file, open a new terminal window and see if you get same message.